# Find all values of the parameter $a$ so that $f(x)= y$ is always positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all values of the parameter $a$ so that $y>0$.

The equation is:

$$y = (a − 1)x^2 − (a + 1)x + a + 1$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here f(x) is a parabola so you should know what it looks like.

The first thing to see is that y tend to infinity when x tend to +/- infinity. This require a-1>0.

Then suppose your parabola is touching the X axe, then it has only one root and $\Delta=0$

Here $\Delta=-3a^2+2a+5$.

Now you just need to find the two roots $a_1$ and $a_2$ of this polynomial. Your interval will be (]$-\infty,a_1$[ $\cup$ ]$a_2,+\infty$[) $\cap$ ]1,$+\infty$[.

Comment: The result is ]5/3,$\infty$[.

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: Your second line is slightly wrong. $y$ does not have to tend to infinity. For example try $a=1$.

Comment: You're right. I should have said that we do not want a line(unless it is parallel to the X axis) so $a \ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the discriminant should be negative but $a-1>0$.
We get
$$(a+1)^2 - 4(a-1)(a+1) < 0 \Longleftrightarrow a^2+2a+1 - (4a^2 - 4) = -3a^2+2a +5 < 0.$$
By using quadratic formula
$$-3a^2+2a+5 = (-3a +5 )(a + 1) < 0.$$
The formula above will have negative value when $a < -1$ or $a > \frac{5}{3}$.
Because the value of $a$ should be greater than 1, so that
$$a > \frac{5}{3}.$$